How do I get JSDoc @typedef and @type to appear in Intellisense of an ASP.NET Core MVC project in either Visual Studio 2022 or Visual Studio Code?
So I've started to document my code a lot more lately as I've not been soloing on a number of projects. In my standard nodejs projects inside VSCode I can create inline @typedef and @type like this:
**
 * Grid column data for mapping/region
 * @typedef {Region}
 * @property {string} regionId - Region ID
 * @property {string} regionName - Region name
 * @property {string} updatedBy - User name that last updated the record
 * @property {string} updatedDate - String version of date the record was last updated
 */
/** @type {Region[]} */
const gridData = oracleData.map((item) => {
    /** @type {Region} */
    const gridItem = {
        regionId: item.regionId,
        regionName: item.regionName,
        updatedBy: item.lastUpdateUserId,
        updatedDate: item.lastUpdateDtmText
    }
    return gridItem
})

and the intellisense works fine, hovering over regionId would produce a tooltip saying (property) regionId: string but in an ASP.NET Core MVC project it says (property) regionId: any and hovering over {Region} produces a tooltip saying type Region = /*unresolved*/ any.
Has anyone had any success using JSDoc inside .js files in either Visual Studio 2022 or Visual Studio Code for an ASP.NET Core MVC project?

I wish someone had pointed out my obvious mistake:"
@typedef {Object} Region

That's all it took and if I had looked at any of my old @typedefs earlier I would never have posted this question.
